# Duplicated content as guest post

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, guest-blogging

I wrote an article in my blog. Then another site in the same niche request me to re-publish the same text in their blog, as guest post, with my bio profile included and backlink to original content. This is good to for me to reach a larger audience.

I known Google hates duplicated content. My understanding here is that Google will know that my blog is the original source, since it's first indexed from there, and the another blog will link the source.

There is any problem here? Should I request for a `canonical` to my blog? Or should I add a last paragraph saying "Original content published XXX"?

Answer (score 1):

Another site will be treat as article submission site, and backlinks from those site doesn't add any value, you can say zero value since it is pure duplicate content.

In another way you can think like that did Google index that duplicate page? if yes then for how long? surely it will gonna remove after some time, so how you get benifitis from it, if it is not index by Google(not by you like using noindex tag).

Google remove such a low quality pages from their index even if they index it in first place, so once they remove such a pages, they also remove the links value which is associated with it.

If you just use it to reach a larger audience then it is totally fine, you don't need to anything. If other webmaster copy such a thing then it's hurts only their site, it doesn't matter he/she take permission or not. But if they use canonical link tag which I think it's hard to setup for individual pages, then it's totally fine and the another site will be in safe mode. Canonical link tag is strong hint to index only your original content, but original content published links at the end of article is not good choice, it's a technique used by spammer, so I will not suggest that.

Comment: apparently the safe way is to request for a canonical to original source.

Comment: You can ask to that guy but most of time it's hard to setup canonical link tag for only one page.